# CKEditor version 4.5.8 disabled in IE 11 & Edge

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, ckeditor, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I'm building a hybrid mobile app with the Ionic framework for android, ios, windows 8.1 and windows 10.

I was searching for a good rich text editor and came across CKEditor.
I've tested the editor on an Android and iOS device and it works perfectly.
When i try the editor on a windows device with Internet Explorer 11 or Edge, the editor is disabled (see screenshot below).

[image: CKEditor disabled]

The console shows the following error on page initialization:

```
APPHOST9602: 'javascript:' is an invalid attribute value and will be
ignored.  Don’t use 'javascript:' URIs in the local context.
```

The HTML code i use is :

```
<div id="ckeditor" ckeditor="options" ng-model="survey.Comments" ready="onReady()"></div>
```

And my controller:

```
angular.module('app.parts')
.controller('CommentsController', function ($scope, App, $ionicHistory, Survey) {

$scope.survey = Survey.getSurvey();

// Editor options.
$scope.options = {
  language: 'nl',
  allowedContent: true,
  basicEntities: false,
  resize_enabled: false,
  startupFocus: true
};

// Called when the editor is completely ready.
$scope.onReady = function () {

  // ...
};

});
```

I use the CKeditor library in combination with lemonade's ckeditor angularjs wrapper

According to the [CKEditor specs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_browsers-section-officially-supported-browsers), the editor should be working on IE 11 and Edge.

To be clear, the CKEditor is disabled on a Windows device (Surface Pro 3 with Windows 10 and laptop with Windows 8.1). When I test CKEditor in Internet Explorer 11 or Edge **webbrowser** on my laptop, it works fine.

I've also tested with CKEditor < 4.4.8 and using the following code snippet:

```
CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
```

Unfortunately, no success.

Anyone else had or has the same issue and knows how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you say, CKEditor is compatible with IE11 and Edge, so it's hard to tell what is wrong without seeing any of your code. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Hello Anna, i've updated my post with some HTML and javascript code. There isn't really anything special with this code. By adding the "ckeditor" directive, angular creates the rich text editor for me. I haven't been able to see anything in my console since i'm having problems loading the project into Visual Studio. We are working on a solution for that matter.

Comment: We've been able to debug the application with VS. I've added the console log in my post.